# Expanding each collectionView cell separately

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a prototype `collectionViewCell` that will be created 4 times. There is a button inside it to expand the cell (something like widget on iOS).

I added a closure to the cell class

```
var expand : (() -> Void)?
@IBAction func pressExpandeBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    expand?()
}
```

Then in the `UICollectionViewController`:

```
enum Style {
    case collapsed, expanded
}

var style = Style.collapsed {
    didSet {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "colorCell", for: indexPath) as? ColorViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.expand = { [weak self] in
                switch self!.style {
                case .collapsed:
                    self!.style = .expanded
                case .expanded:
                    self!.style = .collapsed
                }
            }
        case 1:
            cell.expand = { [weak self] in
                switch self!.style {
                case .collapsed:
                    self!.style = .expanded
                case .expanded:
                    self!.style = .collapsed
                }
            }
        case 2:
            cell.expand = { [weak self] in
                switch self!.style {
                case .collapsed:
                    self!.style = .expanded
                case .expanded:
                    self!.style = .collapsed
                }
            }
        case 3:
            cell.expand = { [weak self] in
                switch self!.style {
                case .collapsed:
                    self!.style = .expanded
                case .expanded:
                    self!.style = .collapsed
                }
            }
        default:
            break
        }

        return cell
    }
return UICollectionViewCell()
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.bounds.inset(by: collectionView.layoutMargins).size.width
    if indexPath.row == indexPath.row {
        switch style {
        case .collapsed:
            return CGSize(width: width, height: 150)
        case .expanded:
            return CGSize(width: width, height: 400)
        }
    }
     return CGSize(width: width, height: 150)
}
```

Now when I press to expand button, the size of cell will increased, but the problem is, the height of all cells will be increased and decreased after taping the button, I don't know how I can tell that the cell that its button is tapped should be resized, not all of them. 
Could anyone help me on this?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you declare 1 var for all the cells

```
var style = Style.collapsed {
  didSet {
     collectionView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

so all cells will act the same , but every cell should have it's own status whether it's collapsed / expanded so declare an array , plus this check `if indexPath.row == indexPath.row {` inside `sizeForItemAt` will be true for all as the variable is for sure equal to itself , hence style size is applied same for all

```
var arr = [.collapsed,.collapsed,.collapsed,.collapsed]
```

then change it according to each cell status by

```
cell.expand = { [weak self] in   
    guard let strSelf = self else { return }
    strSelf.arr[indexPath.item] = strSelf.arr[indexPath.item] == .collapsed ? .expanded : .collapsed
    strSelf.collectionView.reloadData() 
} 

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.bounds.inset(by: collectionView.layoutMargins).size.width 
    return arr[indexPath.item] == .collapsed ? CGSize(width: width, height: 150) : CGSize(width: width, height: 400) 
}
```